# Google analytics reporting API returns incorrect data with paging

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented Google analytics reporting API v4 to get the data stored in Google analytics with one of the e-commerce applications and it sends two report requests to GA side in order to get data with pagination for the first request. one request is sent to get a page of userIds and second request will sent with those userIds to fetch another set of data. This works perfect until in some cases, at the last page it sends some userIds which is not showing in the Google Analytics web UI either. We have a record against each userId in our own database and there is no such record for those incorrect userIds either.

I would be grateful if someone has any idea/clue on this.

Comment: did you check to see if the data is sampled?

Comment: Yes, I've checked in the way that, whether the response is having a samplesReadCounts or samplingSpaceSizes fields with it. but there are no such fields. So I can assume that my response is not sampled. even I roughly calculated the session count for that response and it is very less than the session threshold which applies sampling for a request as per the documentation in Google Analytics reporting API V4.

Comment: @XTOTHEL : do you think this the right way to check the sampling in analytics reporting API?